# SQL Multiple where conditions with multiple limits

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a query that looks something like this

`SELECT id FROM table WHERE (geo = 'AA' AND age = 25 AND gender = 'male') OR (geo = 'BB' AND age = 35 AND gender = 'male') OR .....`

There could be 10k of such conditions.

The issue is that the match is not unique, so say for the geo 'AA', there might be many 25 year old males. I only want a set number of id matching the criteria be returned (random is fine). For example, I want 1 match for `(geo = 'AA' AND age = 25 AND gender = 'male'`) and two matches for `(geo = 'BB' AND age = 35 AND gender = 'male')`

One solution I've tried is this:

`(SELECT id FROM table WHERE geo = 'AA' AND age = 25 AND gender = 'male' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) UNION ALL (SELECT id FROM table WHERE geo = 'BB' AND age = 35 AND gender = 'male  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)`

But in general, there would be too many UNION ALLs and this would produce an error in BigQuery `Resources exceeded during query execution: Not enough resources for query planning - too many subqueries or query is too complex.`

Does anyone have a more efficient solution? Thanks.

Comment: Why 10k such conditions? If you're trying to create a stratified sample, isn't there a way to reduce this to something more manageable?

Comment: @Isolated - these conditions are provided by the user, so they would say, I am looking for people in this postal code with this age and this gender and etc. It's not a stratified sample.

Comment: So a user would say `give me two 25 y/o males in geo AA and one 26 y/o female in geo AA`, and that would be repeated with thousands of variations in one request? How would a user even fill out 10k variations? Or are you collecting requests from many users, then trying to run them at once?

Comment: @Isolated a use would provide a list of all conditions to be matched and submit all at once.

Comment: Is it possible to create groups of GEOs and groups of AGEs, etc to significantly reduce this from 10k to perhaps 50 variations that could be UNION'ed together.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using several wheres, you should use CASE statements. What you can do, Is use a CASE statement for each condition, then you can apply a rank to get the top 1,2, or 3 depending on your needs.

```
WITH case_data AS (    
SELECT 
 CASE 
  WHEN geo = 'AA' AND age = 25 AND gender = 'male' THEN id ,
  WHEN geo = 'BB' AND age = 35 AND gender = 'male' THEN id 
 ELSE NULL as filter_id,
 geo, 
 age
FROM table )

SELECT 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( partition by geo, age ) rank, 
filter_id
FROM case_data 
where filter_id is not NULL
and rank in (1,2,3)
```

Comment: Thanks. So what does `rank in (1,2,3)` do in this case? Is the numbers correspondent to each of the cases (i.e., if I have 3 cases, and the 1st case I want 1 random selection and 2nd case 2, and 3rd case 3, then I do (1,2,3)?

Comment: I am thinking if you have 10k conditions, instead of Case statements why dont you create a lookup table for these conditions and store them there and join to that table ? Wouldnt that be more efficient

Comment: @WinstonLi Ranking by order 1,2,3 would be the first, second, and third element. Also, I think Ziya's comment makes sense, Creating a lookup table or a dynamic query with "EXECUTE INMEDIATE" May do better performance. But it would help if you cared about who is maintaining this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below generic enough approach (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
with matches as (
  select 1 match_id, 1 extract_count, 'AA' geo, 25 age, 'male' gender union all
  select 2, 2, 'BB', 35, 'male'
)
select t.*
from your_table t
join matches m
using(geo, age, gender) 
qualify row_number() over(partition by match_id) <= extract_count
```

As you can see  - you can manage as many match criteria as you have in the `matches` table along with respective number of matches you want to pick for each - `extract_count`

Comment: In the background, you will still be doing unions right? Is that a performance concern?

Comment: not at all! ...